# xcode 6.3 storyboard compiles very slow

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode6, storyboard

Well, I have been facing this issue from long time , the **storyboard** specifically for **iPad**, **compiles very slowly**.

**NOTE:-** *There is no auto-layout issues in the project and the project contains two storyboard one for iPhone and another for iPad. iPhone's storyboard compiles very fast I guess there are few scenes or view controllers are there, but the iPad's storyboard contains 40 scenes or view controllers and more than 30 segues connected to each other.*

Here is the **screenshot**:

[image]

Here is my **mac-mini specification**:-

[image]

> I don't know why I am facing this issue . It will be helpful if
>   anybody knows how to make the compilation faster or is it possible to
>   do so?
>
> I cannot upgrade the RAM or processor, as my other iPhone project's
>   storyboard compiles fast and don't need to do so.

**P.S** This question is not related programming, I have already posted it in Super User site but found no answer yet.If any one  flag the post as inappropriate or not related programming then I will be glad if you let me know where I can post the question to get some feedback on it.

Comment: I have the same problem and with the same Mac Mini (mid 2011) but with 16GB and 2.7Ghz CPU. Your fan works likes crazy every recompile? I believe could be a problem with the hard disk velocity and I have idea to upgrade to SSD but I'm not sure.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue @vizllk ..How did you solve the issue?pls let me know.

Comment: I have SSD but there is no differences, fan works like crazy and it takes a lot of time to see storyboard content